# Как сделать что бы шар отскакивал только от палки?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var pole = document.getElementById('pole');
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
var palka = document.getElementById('palka');
var t = l = true;
var y = 0;
var x = 300;
setInt = setInterval('Pusk()', 5);

function Pusk() {
  ball.style.left = x + 'px';
  ball.style.top = y + 'px';
  if (x >= pole.getBoundingClientRect().width - ball.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
    l = false;
  }
  if (y >= pole.getBoundingClientRect().height - ball.getBoundingClientRect().height) {
    t = false;
  }
  if (x <= 0) {
    l = true;
  }
  if (y <= 0) {
    t = true;
  }
  if (t == true && l == true) {
    x++;
    y++;
  }
  if (t && !l) {
    x--;
    y++;
  }
  if (!t && !l) {
    x--;
    y--;
  }
  if (!t && l) {
    x++;
    y--;
  }
  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
}
pole.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  e = e || event;
  palka.style.left = (e.offsetX - palka.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2) + "px"
});
```

```css
#pole {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

#ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 40px #000;
}

#palka {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="pole">
  <div id="ball"></div>
  <div id="palka"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: От всех границ кроме нижней должен отскакивать,при попадании на нижнюю границу setInterval останавливаем.Как связать попадание шара на палку? Естественно палка передвигается по х.

Answer (score 0):

Постарайтесь в следующий раз называть переменные по-английски вместо транслита - это хороший тон, а слова здесь достаточно простые.

```js
var field = document.getElementById('field');
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
var stick = document.getElementById('stick');
var t = l = true;
var f = false; //окончание игры
var y = 0;
var x = 300;
setInt = setInterval('launch()', 5);

function launch() {
  ball.style.left = x + 'px';
  ball.style.top = y + 'px';
  if (x >= field.getBoundingClientRect().width - ball.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
    l = false;
  }
  if (x >= stick.getBoundingClientRect().left && x <= stick.getBoundingClientRect().right && y >= field.getBoundingClientRect().height - (ball.getBoundingClientRect().height + stick.getBoundingClientRect().height)) {
    //если достигли палки - отскакиваем
    t = false;
  }
  if (y >= field.getBoundingClientRect().height - ball.getBoundingClientRect().height) {
    //если достигли нижней границы - заканчиваем
    f = true;
  }
  if (x <= 0) {
    l = true;
  }
  if (y <= 0) {
    t = true;
  }
  if (t == true && l == true) {
    x++;
    y++;
  }
  if (t && !l) {
    x--;
    y++;
  }
  if (!t && !l) {
    x--;
    y--;
  }
  if (!t && l) {
    x++;
    y--;
  }
  
  if (f) {
    alert('Игра закончена');
    ball.style.left = 300 + 'px';
    ball.style.top = 0 + 'px';
    clearInterval(setInt);
  }
  //console.log(x);
  //console.log(y);
}
field.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  e = e || event;
  stick.style.left = (e.offsetX - stick.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2) + "px"
});
```

```css
#field {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

#ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 40px #000;
}

#stick {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <div id="ball"></div>
  <div id="stick"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Шар" все равно не видит "палку"

Comment: @Евгений, у меня работает, попробуйте замедлить шар

Comment: Странно но все равно не отскакивает от палки

Comment: @Евгений, сейчас попробовал открыть на всю страницу - там не работает, да. Попробуйте встроить на реальный сайт.